# I "go by" this name

Tags: phrase-requests

Often times when I go to fill forms and apply for programs at government agencies or other places, they often ask me whether I have another name that people call me. I'm Chinese and I use my native name in my legal documents, IDs, etc. and Theo is what my friends and other poeple call me. If people asks me next time, is it correct to say "I go by Theo" to mean Theo is the name my friends and other people call me?

Comment: I think it would be unusual phrasing, and suggest you say *"I go by **the name of** Theo"*.

Comment: Perhaps "I am known as Theo" or "You can call me Theo".

Comment: Begging your pardon; “… *but* Theo is what my friends…”.  Also, “people ask” or “someone asks”.

Comment: Also, maybe @Carsogrin and I are a bit late to the party, but you misspelled "Oftentimes" and "people".

Comment: English has so many phrases...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This would be a correct way to say this.

Comment: Here is a reference for that:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_by.

Comment: also http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go+by

Answer (score 2):

"I go by ..." is perfectly fine.

Some other alternatives:

"AKA ..." short for "Also known as ..."

"Call me ..."

"My friends call me ..."

"Alias ..." but this has a criminal connotation.